# URL open , decode encode error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm following a tutorial and this next piece of code:

```
import urllib.request as url

def getTextWaPo(URL):
    page = url.urlopen(URL).read().decode('utf8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    mytext = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('article')))
    return mytext.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?", " ")
```

returns :

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Yet in the documentation I see that encode is a string method. So why do I need byteslike object? How do I remove the special characters within the text if this is not the way to do it?

I've looked around but the answers I came across didn't help me, or I at least don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in replace rather than encode. You're converting the string to bytes format with the encoding, then using replace with strings rather than bytes.

I'm not sure what output you'd expect without an example URL to test it on, but try replacing the return statement with;

```
return mytext.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace(b"?", b" ")
```

Comment: Thnx Andrew because in a Python script I had this line of code ---return float(output[output.index('=') + 1:output.rindex("'")])--- and changed it to ---return float(output[output.index(b'=') + 1:output.rindex(b"'")])--- and then no error anymore.